# Hackintosh / VMWare AMD 7950 Chipset

Tags: macos, windows, vmware, virtualization, logic

I currently have a Mac OS X Mavericks VM running on a Windows 7 machine in VMware Workstation.  I am trying to install Logic Studio 9 and  am unable to install due to the following reason.

```
Logic Studio Installer requires that your system have a Quartz Extreme capable video card.
Logic Studio Installer recommends that your system have 64 MB of VRAM; this system has only 0 MB of VRAM.
```

The chipset installed by VMware is:

```
Chipset Model: VMware SVGA II
Type: GPU
BUS: PCI
VRAM: 32MB
Device ID: 0x0405
Revision ID: 0x0000
```

I have a Sapphire 7950 installed on this machine.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

[Possible hackintosh solution?](http://www.macbreaker.com/2013/03/radeon-7000-hackintosh.html)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because goes again EULA.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about running OSX on non-Apple hardware

Comment: Okay I wasn't sure whether it would be or not. Is this a valid superuser question?

Comment: Btw there seem to be several hackintosh questions on ask different that aren't flagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically the issue here has nothing to do with the Hackintosh. It's a limit on the VMWare graphics card and failing the Logic install checker.

You can try the following:

- Install Logic9 package, right-click and choose Show Original
- Choose LogicStudio.mpkg. Right-click and choose Show Package Contents
- Go to Contents/Resources/Requirements Checker.app
- Right-click, and choose Show Package Contents
- Find Checker.app, navigate to Contents/Resources -> file minsys.plist
- Edit it, replacing every
  "block" with "warn"
- Save the file.

Now run the install and it should pass the check.

This same issue impacts genuine Mac's which don't have the required RAM or graphics cards, etc.

Comment: This is great I will try this.  Would somehow updating the vmware chipset with the correct 7950 actually benefit performance?